# How to set the width of background-color of a div?

Tags: html, css

I have two divs with same background color. How can I set the width of background?

**Expected result**:

[image]

Here is HTML:

```
<div>
    <span>100% width of background</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span>75% width of background</span>
</div>
```

What I tried to do using CSS:

```
div {
    background-color: #fc0;
    margin: 2px;
}
div:last-child {
    background-size: 75%;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/samosfator/3acGS/), of course.

***Is it posible to do this exept of setting `width` of a `div`?***

Comment: background-size ist for background-image only.

Comment: why don't use just the width of he div? http://jsfiddle.net/3acGS/5/

Comment: @StefanoL, it's obviously. I used it to make my explanation more understandable:)

Comment: @Danko, reread the last paragraph of a question. It isn't suitable for me, because width of span can be bigger than width of a div.

Comment: @samosfator no it isn't. You used it in a wrong way and I could assume that you were aware of that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use background gradients with hard stops. Here I'm using custom properties on each element to dynamically set the length value. The CSS rule uses a partial attribute selector to look for the custom property in the style attribute.

```css
div {
  background-color: #fc0;
  margin: 2px;
}

div[style*="--bg-length"] {
  background: linear-gradient(
    to right, 
    #fc0 var(--bg-length), /* the end of the colored segment */
    transparent var(--bg-length) /* the start of the transparent segment */
  );
}
```

```html
<div><span>100% width of background</span></div>
<div style="--bg-length: 300px"><span>60% width of background</span></div>
<div style="--bg-length: 85%"><span>85% width of background</span></div>
<div style="--bg-length: 70vw"><span>85% width of background</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with a simple `background-color`, but you can do it with a CSS gradient.

`background-color` is always treated as a single plain colour for the entire element, but gradients are treated as images, and can be sized. You can also do other things with gradients, such as layering multiple gradients, which can't be done with a simple `background-color`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a 1px image as background something like `background: url(1px.png) repeat-y;` then you can set `background-size:75%;` as it's image now. Making life easier and less/simple code as well.

Comment: That's because you are having minor errors in your fiddle, see this update:http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/74HwS/1/

Comment: Errors:1. your 1px holding image is white so you can't really see it. Make one of your prefered color, I used one of my testing background.2. Your background attribute name is duplicated, so causing an error.3. Not specifying default background size for divs.

Answer (score 0):

you can use gradient:

```
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIxMDAlIiB5Mj0iMCUiPgogICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzFlNTc5OSIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjY5JSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzFlNTc5OSIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjcwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzFlNTc5OSIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIwIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjEwMCUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiMxZTU3OTkiIHN0b3Atb3BhY2l0eT0iMCIvPgogIDwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+CiAgPHJlY3QgeD0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjEiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%, rgba(30,87,153,1) 69%, rgba(30,87,153,0) 70%, rgba(30,87,153,0) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(30,87,153,1)), color-stop(69%,rgba(30,87,153,1)), color-stop(70%,rgba(30,87,153,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(30,87,153,0)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(30,87,153,1) 69%,rgba(30,87,153,0) 70%,rgba(30,87,153,0) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(30,87,153,1) 69%,rgba(30,87,153,0) 70%,rgba(30,87,153,0) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(30,87,153,1) 69%,rgba(30,87,153,0) 70%,rgba(30,87,153,0) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(30,87,153,1) 69%,rgba(30,87,153,0) 70%,rgba(30,87,153,0) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#001e5799',GradientType=1 );
```

[**CSS gradient generator**](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eMCxr/)

Comment: I saw that generator. Thank you. But how to make a hard stop of gradient there?

Answer (score 0):

You should change your CSS to :

```
div {
    background-color: #fc0;
    margin: 2px;
}
 div:last-child {

      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #fc0, #fc0 75%, transparent 75%,     transparent 100%)
}
```

Comment: add a line in last child div element for removing inherit bg color :background-color:transparent;